# Angular: Navigating to location that requires visiting login page first

Tags: angular, url-routing

There's a common UX pattern where, if a user's navigation fails because they need to re-login, the app saves the desired URL and navigates to it once the user successfully submits their credentials on a login page. My first thought on how to do this in Angular is to navigate to the login component from the CanActivate guard (on auth failure) with the intended path supplied as a query parameter (e.g. '/login/?next=somepath'), so login component can complete the originally intended navigation. Is there a better practice for  implementing this pattern, maybe by utilizing state information in the router?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service to store the previously visited route/url and then, on successful authentication, retrieve that url and navigate to it.

I found this code for such a service a while ago in another site:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PreviousRouteService {
  private previousUrl: string;
  private currentUrl: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    // Stores the very first navigated route
    this.currentUrl = this.router.url;
    
    router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.previousUrl = this.currentUrl;
        this.currentUrl = event.url;
      }
    });
  }

  public getPreviousUrl() {
    return this.previousUrl;
  }
}
```

So, you inject this service where you need it (i.e. your login component) and after user successfully authenticates, you can do `router.navigateByUrl(this._previousService.getPreviousUrl())`

Code originally fetched from https://dev.to/slk5611/how-to-access-the-previous-route-in-your-angular-app-5db0

Comment: I already know the intended path inside CanActivate, so I could directly store that into a service and retrieve it later... was hoping for something that leverages the router more, but maybe naively.